# Why does it missing formatting when coppied from PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, clipboard, onedrive, summernote

I am using summernote editor and it is missing formatting when copied and pasted from PDF documents.

This issue is there in all other editors such as google doc and onedrive doc.

But msWord retains formatting when copied and pasted from PDF docs.

Any one understands how MS WORD do that because clipboard does not retain any html tags when copied from PDFs ?

I checked the clipboard when pasted data. it showed following results which contains only div tags.

```
<div>This is Heading1 Text</div><div>This is a regular paragraph with the default style of Normal. This is a regular paragraph with the default style of Normal. This is a regular paragraph with the default style of Normal. This is a regular paragraph with the default style of Normal. This is a regular paragraph with the default style of Normal.</div><div>This is a Defined Block Style Called BlockStyleTest</div><div>This is more Normal text.</div><div>This is Heading 2 text</div><div>This is more Normal text. This is bold, this is italic, and this is bold italic. This is normal. This is in a defined inline style called InlineStyle. This is normal. This is red text. This is normal.</div><div>This block is centered.</div><div>This is left-aligned.</div><div> First item of bulleted list.</div><div> Second item of bulleted list.</div><div>Second paragraph of second item of bulleted list.</div><div> Third item of bulleted list.</div><div>o First item of third item’s nested list</div><div>o Second item of third item’s nested list</div><div> Fourth and final item of main bulleted list.</div><div>This is Normal text.</div><div>1. First item of numbered list.</div><div>2. Second item of numbered list.</div><div>Second paragraph of second item of numbered list.</div><div>3. Third item of numbered list.</div><div>Here is a BMP picture:</div><div>Here is a JPEG picture:</div><div>Here is a PNG picture:</div><div>Here is a table:</div><div>New York Boston Detroit</div><div>Baseball Mets Yankees Red Sox Tigers</div><div>Hockey Rangers Islanders Bruins Red Wings</div><div>Football Giants Jets Patriots Lions</div><div>Here is an embedded Excel spreadsheet:</div><div>pre- post- pre- postdogs</div><div>1234.43 0.33 354.30 777.00</div><div>cats 432.00 -432.20 654.45 333.00</div><div>turkeys 3.30 4.66 34.65 132.10</div><div>fish 52.55 55.33 37.88 31.50</div><div>total 1722.28 -371.88 1081.28 1273.60</div><div>2001 2002</div><div>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States</div><div>This is more Underlined text.</div><div>This is more Strikethrough text.</div><div>Test superscript text. This is superscript texts.</div><div>Test subscript text. This is subscript texts.</div><div>Here are some special characters -!”&amp;’(*)+’./:;?_ÈÓ 12\</div><div>This concludes our test.</div>
```

Comment: Your question is all over the place. First of all, what is being copied from the PDF. Second, to clarify, are you stating that when the PDF text is copied and then pasted into Summernote, Google Docs, etc that it is losing HTML tags (or some other 'formatting') that are present in the copied selection in the PDF document? Third, when you say you checked the clipboard is this the actual clipboard data or is this what is pasted in Word?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.
1. Tables, Headers, Colored text etc
2. Yes
3. I mean actual clipboard which i access via javascript.(e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))

Answer (score 1):

PDF uses PostScript, it seems you are having an issue Copy and Pasting from PostScript to 'Summernote', etc. MS Word apparently spent time over the years to play nice with PostScript, there must be info that Word uses to realize it is PostScript and processes the paste correctly.

Btw, PostScript is so much more than it would seem.

Background info: 
    https://youtu.be/48tFB_sjHgY
    https://youtu.be/guXgBe2wvEA
    https://youtu.be/-cFOsAzigyQ
    https://youtu.be/S_NXz7I5dQc

Workaround:
You could attempt opening the PDFs directly from Word and then Copy and Paste into Summernote. (I have not verified this works)

Conclusion:
I do not see any way to solve your issue as it all depends on the receiving program, in your case Summernote and others.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot.